# Python: Using XPath to get data from a table

Tags: python, xpath

I'm trying to get data from the table at the bottom of http://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/election-2016/delegate-targets/.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = "http://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/election-2016/delegate-targets/"
response = requests.get(url) 
doc = html.fromstring(response.text) 


tables = doc.findall('.//table[@class="delegates desktop"]')
election = tables[0] 
election_rows = election.findall('.//tr')
def extractCells(row, isHeader=False):
    if isHeader:
        cells = row.findall('.//th')
    else:
        cells = row.findall('.//td')
    return [val.text_content() for val in cells]

import pandas

def parse_options_data(table):
    rows = table.findall(".//tr")
    header = extractCells(rows[1], isHeader=True)
    data = [extractCells(row, isHeader=False) for row in rows[2:]]
    return pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=header)

election_data = parse_options_data(election)
election_data
```

I'm having trouble with the topmost row with the candidates' names ('Trump', 'Cruz', 'Kasich'). It is under tr class="top" and right now I only have tr class="bottom" (starting with the row that says "won/target").

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The candidate names are in the 0-th row:

```
candidates = [val.text_content() for val in rows[0].findall('.//th')[1:]]
```

Or, if reusing the same `extractCells()` function:

```
candidates = extractCells(rows[0], isHeader=True)[1:]
```

`[1:]` slice here is to skip the first empty `th` cell.

Answer (score 0):

Not good ( hard-coded ), but run as u want to.

```
def parse_options_data(table):
    rows = table.findall(".//tr")
    candidate = extractCells(rows[0], isHeader=True)[1:]                                                                                                                                             
    header = extractCells(rows[1], isHeader=True)[:3] + candidate
    data = [extractCells(row, isHeader=False) for row in rows[2:]]
    return pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
```